# Swift destructure an optional tuple to individual optional values

Tags: swift, destructuring

Swift supports destructuring.

```
func pair() -> (String, String)
let (first, second) = pair()
```

Is there a way to destructure an optional tuple to individual optional values?

```
func maybePair() -> (String, String)?
let (maybeFirst, maybeSecond) = maybePair()
```

Such that `maybeFirst` and `maybeSecond` are optional strings (`String?`).

Comment: I have a feeling that the behavior you are looking for is `(String?,String?)?` because you may have one value or both, but at the same time you can have a `nil tuple` or a `tuple`, then you'd use a `if let` or `guard let` to unwrapped it `if let (a,b) = maybePair() {}`

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution (thanks to @dfri for simplifying my original attempt):

```
let (a, b) = maybePair().map { ($0, $1) } ?? (nil, nil)
```

If the return value from `maybePair()` is not nil, the closure is
called with `$0` as the unwrapped return value, from which a
`(String?, String?)` is created. Otherwise `map` returns `nil`
and the nil-coalescing operator evaluates to `(nil, nil)`.

Comment: I believe the anon. arguments in the `map` closure needn't be explicitly wrapped as `Optional`'s, as the optionality of these can be inferred from the coalesced tuple, allowing a slightly less ugly alternative: `let (a, b) = maybePair().map { ($0, $1) } ?? (nil, nil)`.

Comment: @dfri: You are right! I *thought* that I had tried that, but apparently not. Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: No feel free to edit yours if you'd like, I just played around with your solution. Somewhat peculiarly my initial, more verbose modification attempt was not accepted by the compiler (`let (a, b) = maybePair().map { (.some($0.0), .some($0.1)) } ?? (nil, nil)`), as it couldn't infer the tuple expression (I guess within the closure). I assume that the implicit `T` to `T?` conversions kicks in _after_ the return from the `map` closure (hence clear in the chain of inferrence), whereas locally in the closure my first attempt failed to supply the wrapped type for the explicit `T` to `T?` conversion?

Comment: While visiting the horrible alternative `let (a, b) = (maybePair() as? (String?, String?)) ?? (nil, nil)`, I'm prompted with a warning that I believe to be faulty/a bug: _"conditional downcast from '`(String, String)?`' to '`(String?, String?)`' is equivalent to an implicit conversion to an optional '`(String?, String?)`'"_. Since tuples aren't "covariant" (don't know if this is the right term in this context), such an implicit conversion should not be possible, right?

Comment: @dfri: I don't know – but the Fix-it produces non-compiling code.